# Vim regex to find numbers that are not part of other words

Tags: regex, vim

I'm writing a syntax file for Vim and am looking for a regex to match (so I can highlight) floating point and integer numbers, but not numbers that appear in words, like variable or function names.

Further the language doesn't like floats that end on a decimal point like `5.` or `3.e9`.  Not matching such numbers is acceptable.  Matching such numbers separately to mark as Error would also be acceptable.

For instance if I have:

```
var1 = 3.2e-9
var2 = atan2(5.3, 7e+02)
var3 = -6
```

Then **only** `3.2e-9`, `5.3`, `7e+02`, and `-6` should be found.  It's ok to do it in multiple steps.

For instance this:

```
[-+]\=\d
```

gets integers, but it would also match the `1` in `var1`.

These two expressions:

```
[-+]\=\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\=\([eE][-+]\=\d\+\)\=
[-+]\=\.\d\+\([eE][-+]\=\d\+\)\=
```

match both floating point numbers with or without scientific notation and integers.  Using these two, we miss miss `5.` and `3.e9`.  (the second is necessary to match numbers that start with a decimal point like `.42`.

Can I tell the regex about preceding characters?

This comes to mind:

```
\A[+-]\=\d\+
```

It would ignore the `1` in `var1`. But it would also match `(5`, causing the parentheses to highlight.

My understanding of syntax files has me writing:

```
syn match myNumber '[-+]\=\d\+\(\.\d\+\)\=\([eE][-+]\=\d\+\)\='
syn match myNumber '[-+]\=\.\d\+\([eE][-+]\=\d\+\)\='

let b:current_syntax = "myLang"

hi def link myNumber Number
```

Is there a was to do syntax highlighting without `regex`?

As pointed out in a comment there may be problems with expressions like `2+3`.  How can I tell that this is not a word?

So what is the best number matching method?

Comment: I think it would be hard to do with `regex`, because your "language" could have expressions, like `var3=3.6+2*var2` or `var3=3.6+2*3` here I guess in first example, only `3.6` should be in your focus, and 2nd example, you want to have 3 highlighted parts: `3.6, 2 and 3` ?

Comment: In your first example `3.6` and the lone `2` should be matched, but not the `3` in `var3` or the `2` in `var2`.  How would things to hightlight without `regex`?

Comment: You might consider taking a look at how the c syntax file matches numbers. Since I believe it already matches all of these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want one of these methods:

Using the beginning-of-word anchor `\<` (:help /\<)

Using a negative zero-width look-behind: `\@<!` (:help /\@

Forcing specific sets characters to occur before the digit, but not including them in the match, using `\zs` (:help /\zs). For example, for only whitespace, newlines, or parentheses you could use `\(\_s\|[()]\)\zs[+-]\=\d\+`

Comment: -1 for not testing before downvoting. Check out this: http://regex101.com/r/qC3rG0

Comment: The question was about regular expressions in the Vim text editor. Not about javascript, php, pcre and python as tested by regex101. If you try the regex on my last line IN VIM, it does in fact match numbers only if they are not part of a word (without the decimal, etc. so it's not a full solution). You shouldn't downvote my answer only because I downvoted yours. Downvote on the answer itself.

Comment: Hey Ben, I've got nothing personal against you. But yours didn't even match what mine matched. So its obvious of what i did. And i downvoted you with a reason, by providing a link

Comment: Answer to my comment in my answer and I'll delete my answer

Comment: I went for the 3rd method.  Preceding my expressions with `\H\zs` finds a non 'head of word' character and ignores it in the matched expression.  This has the benefit of highlighting `2+3` correctly (the plus sign is not included as the number `+3`).